# How to make a npm package from Create React App /build folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, deployment, create-react-app

I have an app, made in create-react-app boilerplate, that i compile and build using npm run build.

I would like to take the folder /build and create an npm package out of it and publish it so i can use this package in other project as a micro app.

Is it possible? how to do it?

Tnx!!

Answer (score 2):

You may check this [this article](https://medium.com/@revanth0212/how-to-create-and-publish-react-components-using-the-create-react-app-9d60583c2161) if you want to make it simple. However, if you want to publish a component or component library than the recommended way is using [nwb](https://github.com/insin/nwb#react-components-and-libraries).

Comment: I want to publish the whole project, not a single component, i want ot be able to do: "import App from "my-npm-package"" and render App as micro frontend

Comment: It's described in the linked article. Did you find it helpful?

Comment: Not really beacuse this article aims to export components, i want to export the whole project. like src/index.js

Comment: Your app a component composed of the smaller components.

Comment: Ok but i need main export like index.js to load all the app.. when doing this: "SET NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && npx babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files" i simply get all the files after transpile.. no a single output file which i can import inside a new project

Comment: Yes, it's so, but module bundler in another project should be able to detect the main file to import since you added `module` property to your `package.json`. If you need to build your project as a single file to import it later via <script> tag, use `nwb`

Comment: To where should i point my module property? do u have example of such package json?

Comment: What are the nwb.config setting for single output?

Comment: As described in the article you should use `dist/index.js` for `main` and `module` fields in `package.json`

Comment: nwb has a template for a single component which may be created by the command `nwb new react-component your-component-name`

Comment: nwb dont create me a index.js file... how to config it to create one?

Comment: Please read nwb docs about es and umd builds https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/guides/ReactComponents.md#preparing-for-publishing

Comment: @metalice did you find a solution to this problem. I would like to the same. I have multiple applications I want to put in a wrapper apllication. I can't import components  because i want to load the whole app

Comment: @Norbert yes. I used single-spa to handle it. See link https://single-spa.js.org/docs/configuration for details. The login, navbar were seperate apps. Navbar app is shown above all apps except login app. all app share node_modules. Check out the link, the architecture is really cool and saved me a lot of headaches.